# Better way than try-catch to pass failure messages back to Web API caller?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services, exception, asp.net-web-api

I've got many Web API calls that delegate to methods in data-layer classes that call my ORM (Entity Framework) and look like this:

```
public OperationResult DeleteThing(Guid id)
{
    var result = new OperationResult() { Success = true };
    using (var context = this.GetContext())
    {
        try
        {
            context.Things.Where(x => x.Id == id).Delete();
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Instance.LogException(ex);
            result.AddError("There was a database error deleting the thing. Check log for details.");
        }

    return result;
}
```

(You may recognize the return value as similar to the [Notification pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/Notification.html).)

So I have many of the same try-catch blocks and it smells bad to me.  I'd like to get rid of them all and use a global exception handler to log errors instead, but in addition to logging, I also need to **pass a message back to the consumer, specific to each different service method**, so that the consumer can perhaps pass the message as the results of the service call appropriately.  Web service consumers, e.g. our web site, ultimately can display the message generated here to clue the user in to the nature of the error.

Can anyone **suggest a better way**? My instinct is to go through and replace with catches of specific exception types, but that seems like a lot of work for zero practical benefit and a harm to my code maintainability.

Comment: Log exceptions in catch block and then  rethrow them. You will have exception logged and client will receive error code 500 with exception detail

Comment: Catching specific exceptions has huge practical benefits: you can tell exactly what went wrong, and return an appropriate error message with more detail. And if something unexpected goes wrong, you can return a "something bad happened" message, directing the user to call support.

Comment: Tom, that eliminates the ability to supply my own message.  Jim, as in this example, I don't need to know what went wrong for this message to be helpful, only that it went wrong and where it went wrong.  It is as though the "something bad happened" case is all I need, but the message for it differs for each context.

Comment: Can you just use a Filter attribute to pass a friendly message? `[FriendlyError("There was a problem deleting the thing."]`. This can inherit from HandleError attribute, and you could do other things like auto-log the message, generate a correlation ID, etc. to tack onto the message. You can do multiple attributes, if you need to do a different friendly message for the type of exception handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to Stuart's answer, you can also use a Filter attribute inherited from `ExceptionFilterAttribute` to modify the response based on any input you require.

Here's a full working example that accomplishes:

- Custom message for exception type
- Modifying the operation result
- Fall through generic message for all exception types

**ValuesController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using Demo.Models;

namespace Demo.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {

        // DELETE api/values/5

        [OperationError("The operation failed to delete the entity")]
        public OperationResult Delete(int id)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("ID is bad", nameof(id));
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5?specific=[true|false]

        [OperationError("The operation tried to divide by zero", typeof(DivideByZeroException))]
        [OperationError("The operation failed for no specific reason")]
        public OperationResult DeleteSpecific(int id, bool specific)
        {
            if (specific)
            {
                throw new DivideByZeroException("DBZ");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("ID is bad", nameof(id));
            }
        }
    }

    public class OperationErrorAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public Type ExceptionType { get; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; }

        public OperationErrorAttribute(string errorMessage)
        {
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        }

        public OperationErrorAttribute(string errorMessage, Type exceptionType)
        {
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            ExceptionType = exceptionType;
        }

        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            // Exit early for non OperationResult action results
            if (actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ReturnType != typeof(OperationResult))
            {
                base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
                return;
            }

            OperationResult result = new OperationResult() {Success = false};

            // Add error for specific exception types
            Type exceptionType = actionExecutedContext.Exception.GetType();

            if (ExceptionType != null)
            {
                if (exceptionType == ExceptionType)
                {
                    result.AddError(ErrorMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Fall through
                    base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else if (ErrorMessage != null)
            {
                result.AddError(ErrorMessage);
            }

            // TODO: Log exception, generate correlation ID, etc.

            // Set new result
            actionExecutedContext.Response =
                actionExecutedContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, result);

            base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
        }
    }
}
```

**Specific exception:**

[image: Specific exception]

**Generic exception:**

[image: Generic exception]

Comment: To address the issue of not losing operation errors that occur during processing, you could have a wrapper helper around any operations that throws a custom OperationException that contains any errors accumulated.

Comment: This is very promising. I will try it.

Comment: This is pretty cool, and better in that it brings the logic closer to the api endpoints. My only reservation is, when thinking about an api, what can a caller actually do with the information? For some errors, the answer is "retry or report", in which case a 500 status code is about all that we need to return. But for usage guidance with a relatively complex resource, this is a really nice approach.

Comment: I think using semantic error codes could help, specific to your domain. I have seen that as a common way to indicate specific errors without using a string-based message (or to accompany it). The error codes are then documented in the API docs and a client can take action based on the codes vs. messages. Getting into more API design and philosophies :D

Answer (score 1):

You could move your logic up the stack into a custom ExceptionHandler. This is a simple example, but the basic idea is to handle specific exceptions and control the status code and (not pictured below) normalize error messages for the caller.

```
public class ApiExceptionHandler: ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        LogManager.GetLoggerForCurrentClass().Error(context.Exception, "Captured in ExceptionHandler");

        if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(NotFoundException))
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult(context.Request);
        }
        else if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(ArgumentException))
        {
            // no-op - probably a routing error, which will return a bad request with info
        }
        else if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(ArgumentNullException))
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestResult(context.Request);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = new InternalServerErrorResult(context.Request);
        }
    }
}
```

Hook this up in the WebApiConfig:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new ApiExceptionHandler());
```

Comment: Good idea, but this doesn't let me customize the error messages based on context (i.e. a different message for each failing database call). I do already have a custom global exception handler.